# What are effective and safe treatments to speed up the healing process of unsightly scabs?

Tags: aloe-vera, benzoyl-peroxide, scab, antibiotic-cream

I have several unsightly scabs in prominent places (handful on face and a couple on arms and hands, but a rather large one on my knee) due to minor cuts I sustained from last weekend's yard work. **What are effective and safe treatments to speed up the healing process of unsightly scabs?**

I know the best thing is to not touch it, keep it clean, etc. (scabs are a sign that the wound is healing), and it'll go away eventually -- but is there a way to speed up that process? These scabs are very noticeable (face, hello!), and I have quite a big presentation at work in a mere 5 days, and I want to look as profession as possible (obviously), and will be wearing a dress, which will reveal the huge scab on my knee.

1. **Does aloe-vera**, typically used for sunburns, **help with the healing process of scabs?** *Is aloe-vera supposed to be kept refrigerated by the way?*
2. I **put an antibiodic-cream on the scab** (to make sure it's clean), but I'm not sure if I should continue doing this or if I'm just interfering with the process?
3. I read that topical gels that contain **benzoyl peroxide or salicylic acid may induce the skin repairing process**, but I'm worried it might just dry it out and make it last longer. **What are common household items that would be composed of these ingredients?**
4. **Are there home remedies that are worth trying?** I already know of the warm-compress, but was wondering if there were more...